# Windows Phone 7 XDocument.Load()

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

Получаю в цикле XML документы. Нижеприведенный код отрабатывает в Windows Phone 8, но на Windows Phone 7.5 (и на эмуляторе и на аппарате) получаю NotSupportedException в методе XDocument.Load(). Надо добавить, что ошибка возникает не всегда. Иногда 5 xml-ек успевают обработаться, иногда 7. Цикл делает около 100 запросов(может ли быть в этом проблема?)

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar);

using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(responseStream);

        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: А приведите полный Exception, а? С вложенными и со стеком. (Как я понимаю, для этого нужно просто сделать `.ToString()`.)

Comment: Уже разобрался. Проблема была в самих XML файлах. Точнее в !DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в !DOCTYPE некоторых XML-документов. На Windows Phone 8 парсер справлялся, на Windows Phone 7.5 решение такое:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar);

using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(responseStream, settings);

    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: Отметьте свой ответ как решение, раз сами разобрались. Вдруг еще кому пригодится.

Comment: Это галочка слева от ответа? Пытался - приходит сообщение, что свой собственный ответ можно пометить как принятый через 2 дня. Помечу через два дня :-)